# Address for OpenLayer plugin to Google Maps

Tags: openlayers

In my office, there is a proxy that allows only a few sites to be accessed. My problem is that I need to access through OpenLayers plugin the Google Maps and I cannot.

What could the address be, so that I can ask my network administrator to insert in the exceptions so that I can view those images?

Comment: is this for qgis?

Answer (score 1):

- `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api` for the apis and
- `maps.gstatic.com` for the files.
- `khm0.googleapis.com and khm1.googleapis.com` for satellite images